# How to enable RT cores on Cuda kernel?

Tags: cuda

From reading the [Wikipead page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_20_series), I understand that GeForce RTX model has RT cores and Tensor cores.
My question is that which cores are used on my Cuda code? Do I have control over that?

I have a ray tracing kernel and want to benefit from the RT cores?
Are the RT cores used by default or there is a flag to enable it?

Comment: None of the special hardware is used unless you specifically have written code for it, and the ray tracing intersection hardware isn't exposed at all in CUDA AFAIK

Comment: the Optix benefits from RT cores though. So I thought it might be possible to use RT cores in Cuda kernels. (why -1 ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, the RT core functionality is not exposed via any CUDA API.  CUDA device code also currently cannot access any RT core hardware.

If you have an application that you would like to use with RT cores, the way to do that is with [Optix](https://developer.nvidia.com/optix).  It's possible for an Optix application to have [interoperability](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/optix/optixapireference/optix__cuda__interop_8h.html) with CUDA.

Comment: Thanks Robert, Are you aware whether this is going to be added to the API in future?

Comment: No, I'm not aware.  However, even if I were, I'm generally not able to comment about NVIDIA's future plans.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella, I am using the latest OptiX 7.5 and I am not an expert in GPU programming. How are the RT cores specified in OptiX ? I guess DLSS is using Tensor cores also. From the sample code I did not find how to explicitely define the cores in code